# How can I display all history files in all branches for selected file when I use Git in Android Studio 4.1

Tags: git, android-studio

I use Git in Android Studio 4.1, I have several branches for my project, such as *master* brach, *TestC* branch, you can see *master brach Image*, *TestC branch Image*.

Now I switch to *master* branch, I hope to see all history files in all branches for the file *PlayInterface.kt*.

After I click *VCS -> Git -> Show History* in Android Studio menu, I find only history files in current master branch for the file *PlayInterface.kt* are listed, you can see *PlayInterface Image*.

I have committed the *PlayInterface.k*t in both *master* branches and *TestC* branch, how can I display all history files in all branches for *PlayInterface.kt* when I locate *master* branch ?

**master brach Image**

[image]

**TestC branch Image**

[image]

**PlayInterface Image**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android Studio and IDEA it is the same: open `Git | Log` toolwindow and select `Path` filter to include files of your interest, and `Branch` filter to include branches of interest (e.g. `All`)

[image]

Another option would be to use `Show All Branches` from "Show File history" toolwindow:
[image]